# Can't get Value from ListPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, listpreference

I can't get value from sharedpreferences in this class.
getDefaultSharedPreferences give the error "The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (HandlingXMLStuff)"

I can get the value from my main class but i can't pass it to the class shown below.

```
public class HandlingXMLStuff extends DefaultHandler {
String Units;

private XMLDataCollected info = new XMLDataCollected();

public String getInformation() {
    return info.dataToString();
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {



    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String unit = prefs.getString("unitsofmeasure", "Fahrenheit");

    Log.d("HandlingXMLStuff", "test" + unit);
    // if (Units == "Farenheit") {
    if (localName.equals("city")) {
        String city = attributes.getValue("data");
        info.setCity(city);
        Log.d("DeskClockActivity", "test" + city);

    } else if (localName.equals("temp_f")) {
        String t = attributes.getValue("data");
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(t);
        info.setTemp(temp);
    }
    /*
     * }/* else if (unit == "C") { if (localName.equals("city")) { String
     * city = attributes.getValue("data"); info.setCity(city); } else if
     * (localName.equals("temp_c")) { String t =
     * attributes.getValue("data"); int temp = Integer.parseInt(t);
     * info.setTemp(temp); } }
     */
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

getDefaultSharedPreferences is taking a context parameter while DefaultHandler class is not a context.

Comment: So is there another way that I would be able to get a value from sharedpreference in the DefaultHandler class?

Comment: just pass the context to your HandlingXMLStuff class and use it for getDefaultSharedPreferences method

Comment: @Mike: Sure, have your `HandlingXMLStuff` constructor take a `Context` reference and use that for interaction with the shared preferences. Alternatively you could set up a listener interface, which your `HandlingXMLStuff` will call methods on when applicable, and abstract the interaction with the shared preferences into some other class that does have a `Context`.